# Video card - pci express security

Tags: wireless, ethernet, gpu

I recently bought a second hand Nvidia video card which runs in SLI mode with my default video card. 
Can it be infected with a malicious program added by the previous owner, 
steal data from the system (as PCIe has DMA) and send it through ethernet/wireless?

Comment: Maybe, yes. But if you are not a spy/NSA agent/supervillain, very unlikely.

Comment: Yeah this would be a DMA attack.

Comment: If there was a malicious code, would it be located in the bios of the video card or can it reside in another place?